# Core Audio: Bizarre problem with pass-through using render callback

Tags: callback, core-audio, render, pass-through

I am implementing an audio passthrough using the RemoteIO audio unit,  by attaching a render callback to the input scope of the output bus (ie the speakers).

Everything works swimmingly, ...

```
OSStatus RenderTone(
                    void *                      inRefCon, 
                    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  * ioActionFlags, 
                    const AudioTimeStamp        * inTimeStamp, 
                    UInt32                      inBusNumber, 
                    UInt32                      inNumberFrames, 
                    AudioBufferList             * ioData)

{   
    SoundEngine * soundEngine = (SoundEngine *) inRefCon;

    // grab data from the MIC (ie fill up ioData)
    AudioUnit thisUnit = soundEngine->remoteIOUnit->audioUnit;
    OSStatus err = AudioUnitRender(thisUnit, 
                                   ioActionFlags, 
                                   inTimeStamp, 
                                   1, 
                                   inNumberFrames, 
                                   ioData);
    if (result)
    {
        printf("Error pulling mic data");
    }

    assert(ioData->mNumberBuffers > 0);

    // only need the first buffer
    const int channel = 0;
    Float32 * buff = (Float32 *) ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;
}
```

until I add that last line.

```
    Float32 * buff = (Float32 *) ioData->mBuffers[channel].mData;
```

With this line in place, no errors, simply silence.   Without it, I can click my fingers in front of the microphone and hear it in my headset.

EDIT: 
    AudioBuffer buf0 = ioData->mBuffers[0]; // Is sufficient to cause failure

What is going on?

It is not an error caused by the compiler optimising out an unused variable.   If I set buff++; on the next line, behaviour is the same.   although maybe the compiler can still detect the variable is effectively unused.

Comment: AudioBuffer buf0 = ioData->mBuffers[0]; //  Is sufficient to cause failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was  the request for data from the microphone was failing the very first time this callback fires.

And what I should have been doing was  examining the return value,  and returning it (ie quitting the callback) if it was not success

What was probably happening was that I was accessing invalid data

It is still rather bizarre, but no need to go into it.